# New Sybase User can't SELECT Tables From Other User

Tags: users, sybase, sybase-sql-anywhere, sybase-central

I am accessing a Sybase database and have created a new user using:

```
CREATE USER "ThisNewUser" IDENTIFIED BY "ThisNewPassword";
```

I then granted privleges:

```
GRANT ALL TO "ThisNewUser"
```

I used the output from this:

```
select 'grant all on ' + name + ' to "ThisNewUser";' from sysobjects where type = 'U' or type = 'P'
go
```

Looking at the results from this query, my new user has all permissions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SU.name, 
                SP.selectauth, 
                SP.insertauth, 
                SP.deleteauth, 
                SP.updateauth, 
                SP.updatecols, 
                SP.alterauth 
FROM SYSTABLEPERM SP
JOIN SYSUSERS SU on SU.uid = SP.grantee
ORDER BY SU.Name
```

When I search for all tables in the current database, I can see the tables I want:

```
select table_name from systable order by table_name
```

When I try doing a basic select query `SELECT * FROM Customers`, I get the error `Table Customer not found`

My queries work just fine if I log in as the root user, but not with my new user account. What am I missing here?

FYI, The server is running `dbeng16.exe`, but when I installed the Sybase Central 16 GUI to connect, I got the message that the DB version was version 10 and needed to be upgraded. I have no trouble accessing the old DB using the `dbisqlc` app, which has let me run all the commands on it, and I exported the DB to a new upgraded DB where I also tested, but neither situations work.

Comment: Does `ThisNewUser` own the `Customers` table? if not, have you tried adding the owner to the query, eg, assuming 'DBA' owns the `Customers` table the query would be: `select * from DBA.Customers`?

Comment: I did try using the owner account as you suggested, it still could not find the table

Comment: what user did you issue the 'grant' commands under?

Comment: I used the same user that had access to those tables

Comment: have you tried issuing the grant's by the user that owns the tables in question?

Comment: I stepped out of the office for a minute, I believe I did Issue the commands from the user that owns the table, but I need to verify that when I get back.

Comment: I found that the table was indeed owned by a different user than the original user I had used. Once I fixed that I was able to query the table using `DifferentUser.Customers` but now I get an error that the associated stored procedure can't be found. When looking at the DB Schema I can see there are a few columns that call stored procedures, but even when I don't ask for those columns it fails.

Comment: Using the command `SETUSER DifferentUser` does let it work, but is there a better way that would let me work under my own account?

Comment: `<object> can't be found` typically means you need to preface the stored proc name with the owner of the proc (as with tables)

Comment: I don't work much with SQLAnywhere, but something you might want to look at  ... though it would be considered a security in hole in a production system ... (as owner of table/proc) `grant <perns> on <object> to public`; alternatively, see if SQLAnywhere has the concept of groups or roles ... you'd add your user to the group (or grant access to the role), then perms would be granted to the group/role